# How to choose number of items to prefetch using UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I was trying to find a way to set a number of prefetched cells for `UICollectionView` but I couldn't. For my horizontal collection with big cells it prefetches only 1 item. Meanwhile, `UITableView` on another screen prefetches ~10 rows.

Is there a way to explicitly tell `UICollectionView`/`UITableView` how many items/rows I want to prefetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not allow you to set a predetermined amount of cells to prefetch, as their documentation notes that

> The prefetch method is not necessarily called for every cell

There are numerous factors that are a blackbox behind whether or not a cell will be prefetched, but some could be current memory available and scroll speed.

[Link to Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching)

[Helpful article breaking down prefetching](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/241-uicollectionview-cell-pre-fetching)